# Why dont we have to import the NgModule?

Tags: angular

I am following an Angular Tutorial [HERE](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#ng-star-inserted).

On Imports, we bring in the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
```

In the @NgModule, we only import BrowserModule & FormsModule.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
],
```

Why dont we import in the NgModel? Is this becuase its a part of the Angular Core Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NgModel` directive is included in `FormsModule`.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Your import of it in your app is enough for getting it available.

Comment: he aske about NgModule  not about ngModel

Comment: Please? Did you read the question before downvoting? `Why dont we import in the NgModel? Is this becuase its a part of the Angular Core Library?`

Comment: YES.  i read . see his code and the details of the question . his title is mistake and need an edit

Comment: Sorry I don't agree with you. He was asking why we don't import NgModel. As you can see in his code, NgModule is already imported.

Comment: if i understood correct from his words - > quote "In the @NgModule, we only import BrowserModule & FormsModule."
he asked why it is not also imported to the decorator like the 2 other modules

Answer (score 0):

From angular 4 docs :

You must import:

```
import { NgModel } from'@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

angular have is own module system. the part of angulat that handle it called "NgModule "
you need to import it when you create a module. but you dont need to import it inside the module... you just use it to create the module .
because that you don't see NgModule  in the import or export section.
read in the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)